# sql - test records are inserted in order

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a table with an skey column (generated by a sequence number) and a timestamp column.

I need to write a query that will find any records with a higher skey but an older timestamp than preceding records as it will indicate an issue.

ie something along the lines of:

```
select * from table
where timestamp < (select max(timestamp) from table where skey less than currrecord)
order by skey desc;
```

Comment: Seems like something that `lag` might help with to do it in a single pass through the data.

Comment: "a higher skey but an older timestamp" - If you are using RAC this is quite normal and nothing to get worried about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `self join` i.e. join the table to itself with the criteria that you have mentioned (SKey and TimeStamp)

```
Select T1.Skey HigherSkey, T2.SKey LowerSkey, T1.Timestamp LowerTimestamp, T2.Timestamp HigherTimestamp
From MyTable T1
Inner Join MyTable T2
    On T1.Timestamp < T2.Timestamp
    And T1.Skey > T2.Skey
```

Answer (score 0):

If your sequence is complete (meaning there are no holes in it) something like this should work:

```
select t2.* from table t1
inner join table t2 on t2.skey = t1.skey + 1
where t2.timestamp < t1.timestamp
order by t2.skey desc;
```

If not, you can use something like this to get the ids:

```
select t2.skey from table t1, table t2
where t1.skey < t2.skey and t2.timestamp < t1.timestamp
group by t2.skey
```